# Is there a way to check if a module is being loaded by multiprocessing standard module in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I believe on Windows, because there is no *fork*, the *multiprocessing* module reloads modules in new Python's processes.

You are required to have this code in your main script, otherwise very nasty crashes occur

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import freeze_support
    freeze_support()
```

I have a bunch of modules which have debug print statements in them at the module level. Therefore, the print statements get called whenever a module is being loaded.

Whenever I run something in parallel all of these print statements are executed.

My question is if there is a way to see if a module is being imported by the *multiprocessing* module, and if so silence those print statements?

I'm basically looking if there is something like:

```
 import multiprocessing
 if not multiprocessing.in_parallel_process:
     print('Loaded module: ' + __name___)
```

I've been unable to find it so far. Is this possible?

Comment: Sanity check: Are you actually using a frozen executable?

Comment: No, I'm just running a python script: "python main.py" it uses the multiprocessing module and its on windows

Comment: Then you don't need `freeze_support()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Python 3.8 and newer use [`multiprocessing.parent_process()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.parent_process) which returns `None` only for the main process and for earlier versions check if `name` attribute's value equals `MainProcess`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
    print('Hello from the main process')
else:
    print('Hello from child process')

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Output:

```
Hello from the main process
Hello from child process
hello bob
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can obtain information about the current process from the instance returned by [`multiprocessing.current_process()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.current_process). In particular the [`Process`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) constructor has a `name` argument that can be used to distinguish between child processes.

Note that in python2, if you do *not* specify `name` explicitly then the module doesn't give **any** guarantee on the format used, hence you *cannot* reliably distinguish between subprocesses and the main process: you *must* always explicitly specify it.

In python3 child processes are guaranteed to have a name with the format of `Process-N` with `N` a positive integer. Note that there is no guarantee on the name of the parent process, hence doing:

```
process.name == 'MainProcess'
```

Is *not* reliable. You should do:

```
import re
re.match(r'Process-\d+', process.name)
```

Comment: Ahhh, too bad. Its not a big problem, just an annoyance.

Comment: *(...) if you do not specify name explicitly then the module doesn't give any guarantee on the format (...)* ? Code in [Python 2](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l106), code in [Python 3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l86). *(...) there is no guarantee on the name of the parent process (...)* ? Code in [Python 2](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l304), code in [Python 3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l305)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost You are only making my point. That's an **implementation detail**. If the documentation doesn't state it, then there is no guarantee and the next bugfix release *can* change that, breaking code that relies on it.

Comment: I see your point and I used to think the same way but I don't any more. As `name` is public property, the value you get when accessing it becomes the de facto public, too. Additionally you refer specifically to Python 2 in one place and Python 3 in another as if there were any difference between them in this regard whereas there is no, which is clear when looking at code.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Python3 is a well-know, **backward-incompatible** version of python, i.e. *you cannot assume that the behaviour of python3 is the same of python2*. This is exactly why you *have* to specify both cases, even if they *happen* to behave the same way. Looking at the source code is *not* a way to document, since source code can be changed at every minor release. Also your argument on the public property does not convince me at all, in particular in this case where the python2 documentation *never* state anything about it.

Comment: *Looking at the source code is not a way to document (...)* In the perfect world it's not, indeed. The reality is that most projects lack proper documentation (Python included) and the source code is the only and the most important point of reference. If you take a look at various discussions around changing some aspect of the code, the recurring theme is that something which is not documented as being public but nevertheless used by users is treated as though it was public. I know it shouldn't be like this but this is the reality.

Comment: Is "Process" a placeholder in your answer? My child processes appear to be called `ForkPoolWorker-\d+`

Comment: @Marses This answer applies to processes created by using the `Process` function without providing a `name`, such as: `multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: print('Hi!'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<Process name='Process-1' parent=38406 initial>` However there are other means to create processes and those might result in different names.