# Python multiprocessing: name of the main process

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the multiprocessing module to run a piece of code on different processes. 
At some point in the code, I need to know whether the code is being executed by the main process or one of the created child processes.

In all cases I've tried, the name of the current process is always "MainProcess":

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.current_process().name
'MainProcess'
```

Is this a python convention I can rely on to be sure that my piece of code is run by the main process (assuming that no other process is named that way)?
Otherwise, is there any other way I should use to know which process is executing a piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that the main process has a different `type` than child processes. This might be a better way to test for it.

Comment: `>>> type(multiprocessing.current_process())`
    `multiprocessing.process._MainProcess`

    `>>> type(Process())`
    `multiprocessing.process.Process`

This looks like an acceptable answer. You should post this as an answer rather than a comment so that I can accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if a module is being loaded by multiprocessing standard module in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216050/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-module-is-being-loaded-by-multiprocessing-standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the main process has a different `type` than child processes. The main process is `mulitprocessing.process._MainProcess` while child processes are `multiprocessing.process.Process`. This might be a better way to test for it.

Now, since the name of the `_MainProcess` type has a leading underscore, it's meant to be "private," meaning it's an implementation detail that could change. That doesn't seem likely, but you could check to see if the current process is *not* of type `Process` rather than checking to see if it is of type `_MainProcess`.

Comment: A note though: the `_MainProcess` class is inheriting from `Process`, which makes `isinstance(multiprocessing.current_process(), multiprocessing.Process)` return `True` from both the main and child processes. 
The solution is working with `type(multiprocessing.current_process()) == multiprocessing.Process` though, as this is not checking the type of the parent classes.

Answer (score 4):

Though one can use `multiprocessing.current_process()`, perhaps a better alternative for it would be to use `multiprocessing.parent_process()`.
For the main process, it will return `None`.

It was added in Python 3.8, therefore wasn't available at the time of the question.